# File Not found issue in implementing Ogg Vorbis in iOS

Tags: ios

I am implementing an OGG Vorbis player in my iOS app for playing .ogg format audio files, the project separately works fine but when adding it to my project, it gives a

```
'vorbis/ivorbiscodec.h' file not found
```

error… any help would be appreciated. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the "Header search paths" under XCode project build settings to locate the headers required.

Comment: Now its giving this error `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PASoundMgr", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ChatViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`